# How to reference a .NET framework v4.0/v4.5.2 instead of v2.0 on macOS?

Tags: .net, macos, command-line, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to use a different .NET framework in my app, ideally v4.5.2.

The problem I have, is that the [latest version for macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos) I could install is *.NET Core SDK v2.1.4 (x64)*, but I need to use at least *v4.0* (e.g. ~*v4.5.2*) for compatibility reasons (see: [`RustFlakes.csproj`](https://github.com/peschkaj/rustflakes/blob/develop/RustFlakes/RustFlakes.csproj#L13)).

---

I've created the project on macOS by the following command:

```
dotnet new console -o myApp
```

I've added a local package by:

```
dotnet add package RustFlakes -s lib/rustflakes/RustFlakes
```

Then my `myApp.csproj` looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="RustFlakes" Version="1.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Output of `dotnet --info` command:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.12
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

I've checked and in `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk` I've got only `2.0.0` installed:

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk
2.0.0  NuGetFallbackFolder
```

---

Changing manually `netcoreapp2.0` to `v4.0` or `v4.5.2` doesn't work. So how I can install and reference a .NET v4.0 or v4.5.2 in my project? Or it's not possible to use it on macOS?

Ideally I'd like to use a command-line, not Visual Studio.

Comment: the .net core framework is entirely different from the .net full framework. It is not possible to use the full framework outside of windows. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) may help explain. It is not possible to reference assemblies that target the full framework in a .net core or .net standard project

Comment: This library does very little.  BigInteger is supported by .NETCore so rebuilding it from source to target .NETCore 2.0 should not be a problem.